# Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding, when trying to install packages on venv

Tags: python, pip, package, environment-variables, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment through `python -m venv env` in python and tried to install packages with pip on it. I've got this error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I'm using Windows, does it has something to do with the environment variables? (PYTHONPATH, PYTHONHOME)

Comment: how do you create venv ? What system do you use (Windows/Linux/MacOS) ? What module do you try to install ? On Linux I don't need `PYTHONPATH, PYTHONHOME` to use `venv` and install modules in venv but maybe your system need it.

Comment: I created the venv using `python -m venv venv`

Comment: I wouldn't use name `venv` because it can make conflict with module `venv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you have to reinstall python and check **Add Python to environmental variables** in Advanced Options.

Comment: That option doesn't appear when installing from the Store.